# Print array which contains arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, printing, foreach

```
function PersonAMK(vn, ln) {
this.nachname = ln;
this.vn = vn;
this.marks = [];

this.marks.push([4, 67, 5]);
this.marks.push([41, 63, 5]);
this.marks.push([4, 67, 55]);
} 

var peprson = new PersonAMK('Unknwon', 'Unknown');


peprson.marks.forEach(function callBack(arrSch1, arrSch2) {
  arrSch1.forEach(function callBack(nod1) {
    console.log(nod1);
  });
  arrSch2.forEach(function callBack(nod1) {
     console.log(nod1);
  });
});
```

I get the Error: arrSch2.forEach is not a function

I don't actually understand why arrSch2.forEach is not function. Isn't the second value of marks an array with the values [41,63,5];?

Comment: You don't need `arrSch2.forEach()`, you're already enumerating through the 2d array with the `peprson.marks.forEach()` and `arrSch1.forEach()` loops.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument passed to `forEach` is an `index`. So, `arrSch2` is actually just a number. The `forEach` method does not exist on a number.

Here is a different perspective:

```
peprson.marks.forEach(function callBack(arrSch1, index) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback function takes three arguments:

1. currentValue - The current element being processed in the array.
   index
2. index - The index of the current element being processed in the array.
3. array - The array that forEach() is being applied to.

arrSch2 is a number not an array.

Change your code to this - I removed second forEach call:

```js
function PersonAMK(vn, ln) {
this.nachname = ln;
this.vn = vn;
this.marks = [];

this.marks.push([4, 67, 5]);
this.marks.push([41, 63, 5]);
this.marks.push([4, 67, 55]);
} 

var peprson = new PersonAMK('Unknwon', 'Unknown');


peprson.marks.forEach(function callBack(arrSch1) {
  arrSch1.forEach(function callBack(nod1) {
    console.log(nod1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The second element of the array is [41, 63, 5], but that's not what's passed in in your arguments. If you just want to iterate over the array, then something like the following will work:

```
    function PersonAMK(vn, ln) {
    this.nachname = ln;
    this.vn = vn;
    this.marks = [];

    this.marks.push([4, 67, 5]);
    this.marks.push([41, 63, 5]);
    this.marks.push([4, 67, 55]);
    } 

    var peprson = new PersonAMK('Unknwon', 'Unknown');


    peprson.marks.forEach(function (arr) {
      arr.forEach(function (nod1) {
        console.log(nod1);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simple for Loop.

```js
function PersonAMK(vn, ln) {
this.nachname = ln;
this.vn = vn;
this.marks = [];

this.marks.push([4, 67, 5]);
this.marks.push([41, 63, 5]);
this.marks.push([4, 67, 55]);
} 

var peprson = new PersonAMK('Unknwon', 'Unknown');

   for (i = 0; i < peprson.marks.length; i++) { 
      for (j = 0; j < peprson.marks[i].length; j++){ 
          console.log(peprson.marks[i][j]);    
      }
   }
```

Try out this. Using `JSON.stringify()` method. Gives the following output for this: `{"nachname":"Unknown","vn":"Unknwon","marks":[[4,67,5],[41,63,5],[4,67,55]]}`. You need to iterate over `peprson.marks` Remember `peprson.marks` contains arrays over each index. Good Luck!!